# Error: Problem fetching info -- Error checking for updates

Tags: daemon

I am all synched up, When I try to mine it says "v6 update needed". When I try monerod.exe  and use the command "update check" it says Error: Problem fetching info -- Error checking for updates"
 When I try "update download" I always get "Error: Problem fetching info -- Error checking for updates"

Answer (score 1):

The "v6 update needed" is probably a mangling of the status line, right ? If so, it's telling you it's been a while without an update. It turns out there's none available right now, but it is expected to be very soon.

As for the "Error: Problem fetching info -- Error checking for updates", it's possibly because you build monero yourself. If this is the reason, I believe current master handles it correctly.

It could also be due to DNS problems. You can check that by setting the "DNS_PUBLIC" environment variable to "tcp", which will use Google's DNS server via TCP, as many DNS servers don't support DNSSEC well. In the current code, the Google DNS server is replaced by a selection of non Google servers, and you can select your own preferred server too.